# JSF PrimeFaces back button

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Hi I use JSF and PrimeFaces and I'd like to make button called back which will do the same as back button in browser. Can someone tell a method how to achive this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<p:commandButton value="GO BACK!" onclick="window.history.back();"/>
```

Comment: @YanSklyarenko OP requested a button that has the same functionality as the back button from the browser, using JSF and PrimeFaces...

Comment: Works fine for me :-) Dont understand the problem. Is it that it should be named "back" instead?

Comment: The point of my comment was about adding more explanation to the answer. Perhaps, this is not to case for this particular answer - it seems to be self-explanatory. Sorry, I was probably too quick, ignore my initial comment :)